# how to do exact search or filtering in azure search service?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I am very new to the azure search service. I created an index and uploaded my data there.

say my data has these fields:

```
ArticleId
Author
Abstract
```

In some cases, what I want is to return article with id 1 or 5.

In the search explorer, how can I construct query string to do this exact search or filter?

I tried:

```
&search=1
&search=ArticleId:1
```

but it seems not returning what I am looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [Azure Search filter syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn798921.aspx).

For your specific example, try `&$filter=ArticleId eq 1`